# How can I create row numbers defined only by the previous row's value?

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

This is a task previously accomplished by a cursor in a really old T-SQL script that I now have to get rid of. For a person in a table ordered by dates, I have a value indicating a sequence is starting, then continuing, and then when a new one starts (indicating the old one has ended). I cannot figure out how to get each of these sequences to have row numbers. I had something similar in an R codebase a few years ago I used RLE for but this has me stumped. I need to get from this:

```
ID  STATUS              DATE        A       B
1   START               2000-01-01  1       1
1   CONTINUATION_A&B    2000-01-02  NULL    NULL
1   CONTINUATION_A&B    2000-01-03  NULL    NULL
1   START               2000-01-04  1       1
1   START               2000-01-05  1       1
1   CONTINUATION_A      2000-01-06  NULL    NULL
1   CONTINUATION_A      2000-01-07  NULL    NULL
```

To this:

```
ID  STATUS              DATE        A       B
1   START               2000-01-01  1       1
1   CONTINUATION_A&B    2000-01-02  2       2
1   CONTINUATION_A&B    2000-01-03  3       3
1   START               2000-01-04  1       1
1   START               2000-01-05  1       1
1   CONTINUATION_A      2000-01-06  2       1
1   CONTINUATION_A      2000-01-07  3       1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What database and version are you using? The exact variety and version will absolutely have a significant impact on the best answer here. For example, MySql 5.7 and earlier and Sql Server 2012 and earlier will need very different code than later versions.

Comment: I will be writing the solution in Spark SQL which is a subset of ANSI SQL 2003 IIRC.

Comment: Then you're in luck: it looks like Spark SQL has support for [the row_number() function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-window.html)

Comment: How is this A/B column numbering supposed to work?

Comment: If it's continuation_a&b the increment a and b columns and if it's continuation_a then increment just a. Start sets them both at 1 but I have solved my problem up to that point. I think I should probably have just included A or B as the solution could be adapted to combinations of columns.

Comment: @CClarke I kinda figured that out. But the last row has the wrong value in column A then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with A as (
    select *,
        count(case when status  = 'START' then 1 end) over (order by "date") as grp
    from T
)
select *,
    count(case when status in ('START', 'CONTINUATION_A', 'CONTINUATION_A&B') then 1 end)
        over (partition by grp order by "date") as A,
    count(case when status in ('START', 'CONTINUATION_A&B') then 1 end)
        over (partition by grp order by "date") as B
from A;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=225a1e37236c18fbb7bdbb76d7ad93dc

This assumes that counters always begin at one. That could be adjusted if necessary with expressions like these:

```
min(A) over (partition by grp) - 1 /* offset for A */
min(B) over (partition by grp) - 1 /* offset for B */
```

Comment: Thank you! I've never used count or sum with an over clause - I must learn the technique properly.

Comment: @CClarke They're basically the same here so not sure why I had mixed them. It's definitely handy to wrap your head around the analytic functions.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, but important for eventually answering the question and too long for a comment (hence community wiki).

---

I see this:

> in a table orderd by dates

... but I don't see any dates in the question. Where is the date field in your sample data? We need to at least know it's name to give you good code.

One thing to get drilled into your head is tables **never** have any inherent or natural order. While the primary key/clustered index or insert order may seem like a natural table order, there are plenty of things that can mess with this, and unless you are explicit in your code about the order of your records the database is free to give you results in any order it finds convenient. That is, if there's not a fully-deterministic `ORDER BY` clause, the ordering of the results for the same query can and does change from moment to moment, depending on things like what other queries are currently running to access the same data or what pages or indexes are already in memory.

This means we need to be able to reference a field in the table to enforce the desired ordering... we need to know about that date field to write the correct SQL statement.

Comment: There is a very precise order by statement which gives me the longer version of what I've provided in the original question. So I guess I should have said assuming this data is the result of an order by statement - how can I also create the columns I need?

Comment: @CClarke The goal here is to use a windowing function, so we still need the date field as part of the data.

Comment: Sorry - of course - I've added the date column. Thanks.