# SQL code in order to select second value after first one

Tags: mysql, sql

[image]

Help needed. Could someone help to generate code which would take only second value of IncurredAmount after first one from the same policid.

```
SELECT claims.claimid, claims.policyid, claims.IncurredAmount
FROM claims
GROUP BY claims.claimid, claims.policyid, claims.IncurredAmount
HAVING (((claims.policyid)=62));
```

That's what I have. I tried to take one policyid (62) in order to have less entries. But there I stuck. have no clue what clause can be used in order to take only second entries for all entries.

Comment: please tag with database platform.  Don't post pics, post text

Comment: Show us the SQL code that you already have.

Comment: Define "2nd". What determines the order you see for these rows? I can infer `claimid`, but I need to know for sure. Read my recent answer here for info on what I'm asking about: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70024048/3043

Comment: Also: what version of MySql? The answer here depends greatly on whether your system is running 8.0 yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, though whether it will work depends on the version of your database:

```
SELECT claimid, policyid, IncurredAmount 
FROM (
    SELECT *, 
        row_number() over (partition by policyid order by claimid) rn
    FROM [MyTable]
) t
WHERE t.rn = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution exists for the old MySql versions (pre 8.0)

```
select *
from claims t
where exists (
   select 1
   from claims t2
   where t2.policyid = t.policyid
     and t2.claimid <= t.claimid
   having count(distinct t2.claimid) = 2
)
order by policyid, claimid
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.5&fiddle=c37f6db5238d12df80473f8574eb0d40)*

Although it's more equivalent to a [DENSE_RANK](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-dense_rank-function/).
I.e. if there's more with the 2nd lowest claimid then it'll get more than 1.